# Multiplying a 3D numpy array by a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I need to multiply a 3D numpy array by a 2D numpy array.

Let's say the 3D array A has shape `(3, 100, 500)` and the 2D array B has shape `(3, 100)`. I need element wise multiplication for each of those 500 axes in the 3D array by the 2D array and then I need to sum along the first axis of the resultant array yielding an array of size `(100, 500)`.

I can get there with a couple of for loops, but surely there must be a numpy function which will achieve this in 1 line? I have had a look at `np.tensordot`,  `np.dot`, `np.matmul`, `np.prod` and `np.sum`, but none of these functions will do exactly that.

Comment: Please provide an example. Just to be clear, are you asking about element-wise multiplication in the first step?

Answer (score 1):

We can exploit numpy broadcasting:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3,100,500)
b = np.random.rand(3,100)

# add new axis to b to use numpy broadcasting
b = b[:,:,np.newaxis]
#b.shape = (3,100,1)

# elementwise multiplication
m = a*b
# m.shape = (3,100,500)

# sum over 1st axis
s = np.sum(m, axis=0)

#s.shape = (100,500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily express these operations using `np.einsum`, in this case:

```py
np.einsum("ijk,ij->jk", A, B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast by adding a new unit axis to the 2D array:

```
np.sum(A * B[..., None], axis=0)
```

`None` in an index introduces a unit dimension at that position, which can be used to align axes for broadcasting. `...` is shorthand for `:` as many times as there are dimensions: in this case it's equivalent to `:, :` since `B` is 2D.

An alternative way to write it would be

```
(A * B.reshape(*B.shape, 1)).sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following which should work,

```
np.sum(A.T*B.T,axis=-1).T
```

This will give you shape (100,500)